# Bad Request -Post method - JSON DateTime issue

Tags: json, rest, wcf, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have a Visual Studio (2015) project that includes a client part (Xamarin.Forms PCL) and a web service part ( WCF Rest). The web services use edmx to communicate with the database ( SQL Server 2016). JSON is used to exchange the data.

I'm new to creating/consuming WCF Rest services. I have no issue using the GET method but I'm stuck with an issue with a POST method.

This method is part of a service that works well: no issue for a GET based method. It works well when I test it from a URL or from my client ( PCL Xamarin.Forms).

The POST method (my first ever) is a bit more problematic.

It's supposed to create a new record in a table in SQL Server (2016).

When I use Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) to test it, it already has an issue: it creates a record in the table but the object has two dates and the two dates are replaced by 1970-01-01.

When I use my client to contact the web service:I get 'Bad Request'.

I looked for a solution and found that instead of placing the Datetime value, it was best to place the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01.

I used this advice in Postman and noticed the creation of a new line worked fine.

Body of the Postman request :

```
{
"Reservation_Utilisateur_Id" : "4", 
"Reservation_Velo_Id" : "2",
"Reservation_DateDebut" : "\/Date(1245398693390)\/",
"Reservation_PeriodeDebut" : "matin",
"Reservation_DateFin" :"\/Date(1245398693390)\/", 
"Reservation_PeriodeFin" : "matin"
 }
```

Now, I'd like to know how to get that object to send to the server . How can my object be serialized like above?

I looked for a solution unsuccessfully.

I keep on getting "There was an error deserializing the object of type BikeSharingService.Reservation. DateTime content '2016-08-22T00:00:00+02:00' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON."

Could someone please give the newbie that I am an explanation and maybe some code that works?

Here is my code:

My contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "create",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Reservation create(Reservation reservation);
```

The service method:

```
    public Reservation create(Reservation reservation)
    {
        using (MyEntities bse = new MyEntities())
        { 
                Reservation re = new Reservation
                {
                    Reservation_Utilisateur_Id = reservation.Reservation_Utilisateur_Id,
                    Reservation_Velo_Id = reservation.Reservation_Velo_Id,
                    Reservation_DateDebut = reservation.Reservation_DateDebut,
                    Reservation_PeriodeDebut = reservation.Reservation_PeriodeDebut,
                    Reservation_DateFin = reservation.Reservation_DateFin,
                    Reservation_PeriodeFin = reservation.Reservation_PeriodeFin,
                    Reservation_DemandeRecupDomCli = reservation.Reservation_DemandeRecupDomCli

                };
                bse.Reservations.Add(re);
                bse.SaveChanges();
            return re;
        }
    }
```

On the client side :

```
   const string Url1 = "http://localhost:51843/ServiceReservation.svc/create";

   public async Task<Reservation> create(Reservation reservation)
    {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reservation);
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(Url1,
                            new StringContent(
                               json,
                            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                            return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reservation>(
            await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());            
    }
```

Then calling the method on the client side :

```
        Reservation re =new Reservation();
        re.Reservation_Utilisateur_Id = 4;
        re.Reservation_Velo_Id = 2;
        re.Reservation_DateDebut = DateTime.Now.Date;
        re.Reservation_PeriodeDebut = "matin";
        re.Reservation_DateFin = DateTime.Now.Date;
        re.Reservation_PeriodeFin = "matin";
        re.Reservation_DemandeRecupDomCli = 1;

        Reservation resultat = await reManager.create(re);
```

What I get :

> False Bad Request Method: POST, RequestUri:
>   'http://localhost:51843/ServiceReservation.svc /create', Version: 2.0,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers: {   Accept:
>   application/json   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 407 }  BadRequest
>   1.1
>
> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   BikeSharingService.Reservation. DateTime content
>   '2016-08-22T00:00:00+02:00' does not start with '/Date(' and end with
>   ')/' as required for JSON.

Comment: Json doesn't define a standard date format, but it's worth noting that Json.Net (which is used a lot by the web-facing parts of the .Net framework) supports multiple formats (and even custom ones) so if you can decide on a standard which works for all your clients, you can configure the Json (en/de)coding to use it natively. See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm for more information

Comment: @Basic Thank you so much. I used the following information provided at the page you suggested and it worked. So simple, actually :-)     JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
       DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
   };
   string microsoftJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, microsoftDateFormatSettings);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Promoted from a comment]

Json doesn't define a standard date format, but it's worth noting that Json.Net (which is used by most of the web-facing parts of the .Net framework) supports multiple formats out of the box (and even custom ones).

If you can decide on a standard which works for all your clients, you can configure the Json (en/de)coding in .Net to use it natively.

See http://newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm for more information and details on how to specify a date format handler.

[Example code from link]

```
public void WriteJsonDates()
{
    LogEntry entry = new LogEntry
    {
        LogDate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        Details = "Application started."
    };

    // default as of Json.NET 4.5
    string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);
    // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"}

    JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
    };
    string microsoftJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
    // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"\/Date(1234656000000)\/"}

    string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
    // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":new Date(1234656000000)}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to use is the [Epoch DateTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or [Unix DateTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

To convert the DateTime object to epoch datetime you can create a helper method. It is either milliseconds or seconds from 1/1/1970.

Also if needed you can use the [Noda DateTime](http://nodatime.org/) instead of the .NET which has the method in it to convert.

You can create a New class with `string` data type for DateTime and have a Casting specified. Or you can write your on custom Serialize method.

By default DateTime format after serialization would be [ISO 8601 Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Code to convert to Unix or Epoch Date time :

```
private static readonly DateTime EpochDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public static long ConvertDateTimeToUnixTime(DateTime date, bool isDatarequiredInMilliSeconds = false, DateTimeKind dateTimeKind = DateTimeKind.Local)
{
     return Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.SpecifyKind(date.Value, dateTimeKind).ToUniversalTime() - EpochDateTime).TotalSeconds) * (isDatarequiredInMilliSeconds ? 1000 : 1);
}
```

You can use the following if you need to convert back([source](http://yassershaikh.com/convert-date-time-to-json-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/)):

```
var milliseconds = "/Date(1245398693390)/".replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1');
var actualDate = new Date(parseInt(milliseconds));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I actually used a JsonConverter as suggested by Basic and it worked. Anyway, thank you for answering my call for help.